# Python keeps crashing with pygame function

Tags: python, pygame

I can't get python to work when I am using my Raycast function to display images, how do I fix this?

I tried moving some variables and played around with the function, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

Screen = "Title"
DB = 0
Width = 800
Height = 600

Frame = pygame.display.set_mode((Width,Height))
pygame.display.set_caption("GAME")
FPS = pygame.time.Clock()

def Raycast(RayXPos, RayYPos):
    RaycastThis = pygame.image.load(TTR)
    Frame.blit(RaycastThis, (RayXPos, RayYPos))
    Loop = True
    while Loop == True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                exit()
    pygame.display.update()

    FPS.tick(60)

    while Screen == "Title" and DB == 0:
        TTR = 'TitleScreenSmall.png'
        Raycast(0, 0)
```

I expected the frame to display the image (the same size as the window) and it instead crashed, and I can't run the program

Comment: Do you receive any error message?
Have you tried another pygame function where it worked?

Comment: Your given code has an infinite loop for me (after repairing the lack of a `png` file); no crash.

Comment: @Alex_P No, no error, and yes I have tried a few, but none work.

Comment: @Prune What does that mean exactly, It still does not work

Comment: @CyleLinin What did you not understand?  I can't tell you "what does that mean" when I don't have a referent for "that".

Comment: @Prune It is just that you said "Your given code has an infinite loop for me..." and the part I'm paying attention to is "(after repairing the lack of a .png file), no crash" the context does not help since I have a .png file, I hope I can clear this up, I am just trying to recreate a game, and In doing so I can't figure out why it will not display AND it crashes, even if it were not to crash it will not display.

Comment: *You* have a png file, but you didn't include one in your posting.  If you have no message, I don't think you have a "crash".  What happens when you run it?  This is part of the MCVE I cited above.

Comment: When *I* run the program, it merely sits in the infinite loop -- no crash.

Comment: @Prune ok, when I run it this is what happens:1. It has a totally empty frame no .png 2. It uses the sandtimer (AKA "loading...") mouse 3. then a message that pops up saying "python is not responding would you like to exit the program" and it gives me an option to exit or to wait until theres well... (Not an error). and yes this happens for any other program if it crashes, this one does not make sence. also what is MCVE?

Comment: (1) That's an infinite loop, not a crash.
(2) MCVE is referenced with a link in my first comment.

Comment: @Prune I've rolled back the "auto-destructive" edit, please check, thanks

Comment: Your current code has incorporated that infinite loop into the function.  This version doesn't call `Raycast` at all; it defines the function and exits.  If it *did* call this version of the function, you'd have infinite recursion and you'd overflow the recursion limit.

I'll hold off debugging until you've worked through the posting guidelines and provided that MCVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the infinite loop:

```
while Screen == "Title" and DB == 0:
    TTR = 'TitleScreenSmall.png'
    Raycast(0, 0)
```

Since the loop control variables `Screen` and `DB` never change, you have no way to exit the loop.  You're stuck here, eternally repeating a function that does very little, and includes no changes to observe.

See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Comment: Thank you, It works now, I guess I am stupid! :) "that was not a dis because I think you are smarter (which you are) I am just really dumb"

Comment: Been there, done that, have infinite t-shirts ... :-)